# Set Content inside Interface Java

Tags: java, oop

I'm just learning this interface and now I'm faced with the problem of how to give content inside interface.

I read this article 
http://pixelscientists.com/blog/posts/drag-and-drop-inventory-with-libgdx-part-i

and its content made me think about something - when he uses interface inside that

```
public interface SlotListener {
void hasChanged(Slot slot);
}
```

and he also creates this

```
private void notifyListeners() {
    for (SlotListener slotListener : slotListeners) {
        slotListener.hasChanged(this);//this is Slot class
    }
}
```

How do I give that hasChanged() method content?
I really don't grasp the idea of that interface...
I mean, no content inside hasChanged() (of course because it's am interface) but why does it point back into Slot class? and what content does that method take and how?

Maybe you need to see the link above about this problem.

I already take Googled to learn about interfaces but I only found basic tutorials, not cases like this. I also already asked about this problem in some communities with no result.

Comment: java interfaces must be IMPLEMENTED by a class. Simply create a new class that implements your SlotListener interface. Your new class then must provide the void hasChanged(Slot slot); method implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the typical case of the Observer Design Pattern. In this design pattern you have a collection of listeners (your SlotListener) and an object (your Slot) that will notify to his listeners when something has changed. 
Your Slot class should also contain a method `addListener(SlotListener sl)` that will add a listener to your slotListeners list.
After that you just have to create a class that implements the `SlotListener`

```
public class MyListener implements SlotListener{
    void hasChanged(Slot slot){
        System.out.println("Slot " + slot.toString() + " has changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah there is method addlistener inside Slot class. So now what i must do to give content inside that method is create object that slot class inside other class that iplement slot listener and then access it from there?

Comment: What do you mean by 'give content inside that method' ?

Comment: what i mean content is code inside hasChanged(). i mean in Slot class, method slotListener.hasChanged(this); called (there is addlistener like u said), then if i want give content inside that slot class' hasChanged, i must create another class that implement slotlistener and then create Slot object inside another class, so when i call that slot.addListener() , hasChanged inside slot will refer to hasChanged inside another class. Am i right?

Comment: I think you are saying it complicated but I understood :) try to make a project in java which uses this pattern or search for informations on internet

Answer (score 1):

An `interface` is not a real class. It just has some method signatures in it. Real classes implement an `interface` by implementing all the methods in an `interface`.

SlotListener is an interface. When you want to implement this interface you should create a class that has `hasChanged(Slot slot)` method.

```
public class realClass implements SlotListener {
    public void hasChanged(Slot slot){
        //Some code here...
    }
}
```

Read for more information about Interfaces.
[Interfaces Tutorial by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [what is an interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

When you an an interface, somewhere else you have a class that is implementing the interface. The implementing class is then providing concrete methods for the interface methods.

Have a look at the class : [SlotActor.java](https://github.com/PixelScientists/libgdx-utils/blob/master/core/src/com/pixelscientists/gdx/inventory/SlotActor.java) it @Override and implements the interface method:

```
public class SlotActor extends ImageButton implements SlotListener {

   // some other code
   @Override
   public void hasChanged(Slot slot) {
       setStyle(createStyle(skin, slot));
   }
}
```